# Trying to use a uint*& as a const unit*& fails: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const uint8_t*&’ from expression of type ‘uint8_t*

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, reference, constants

The following code fails to compile for me (gcc 4.6.3, Ubuntu 12.04):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void adjustBuffer(const uint8_t *&buf, size_t &bufSize, size_t len)
{
    buf += len;
    bufSize -= len;
}                

uint16_t packInt(uint8_t *&buf, size_t &bufSize, int value)
{
    size_t valueSize = sizeof(int);
    *reinterpret_cast<int *>(buf) = value;
    adjustBuffer(buf, bufSize, valueSize);
    return valueSize;
}

bool unpackInt(const uint8_t *&buf, size_t &bufSize, int &value)
{
    value = *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(buf);
    adjustBuffer(sizeof(int));
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    static const size_t BufSize = 100;
    size_t bufSize = BufSize;
    uint8_t buf[BufSize];
    uint8_t *buf_ptr = buf;
    packInt(buf_ptr, bufSize, 1);
    bufSize = BufSize;
    int x;
    unpackInt(buf, bufSize, x);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
$ make CXXFLAGS="-Wall -g" ref_to_ptr
g++ -Wall -g    ref_to_ptr.cpp   -o ref_to_ptr
ref_to_ptr.cpp: In function ‘uint16_t packInt(uint8_t*&, size_t&, int)’:
ref_to_ptr.cpp:15:41: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const uint8_t*& {aka const unsigned char*&}’ from expression of type ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’
ref_to_ptr.cpp:5:20: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void adjustBuffer(const uint8_t*&, size_t&, size_t)’
ref_to_ptr.cpp: In function ‘bool unpackInt(const uint8_t*&, size_t&, int&)’:
ref_to_ptr.cpp:22:29: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘const uint8_t*& {aka const unsigned char*&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘unsigned int’
ref_to_ptr.cpp:5:20: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void adjustBuffer(const uint8_t*&, size_t&, size_t)’
ref_to_ptr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ref_to_ptr.cpp:35:30: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘const uint8_t*& {aka const unsigned char*&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’
ref_to_ptr.cpp:19:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘bool unpackInt(const uint8_t*&, size_t&, int&)’
make: *** [ref_to_ptr] Error 1
```

It seems the compiler has trouble assigning a reference to uint8_t* (uint8_t *&) to a const uint8_t *& (which IIRC is a reference to pointer to const). First, I don't understand why it tries to assign a pointer to uint8_t and not a reference to a pointer. Second, shouldn't the conversion work? You can convert uint8_t * to const uint8_t *, why wouldn't converting references to both types work?

Of course, adding an adjustBuffer() that takes a const uint8_t *& works, but I'd like to understand why

Comment: Remove the const operator on buf since you are actually changing it

Comment: @Sednus the const is for the pointed-to type, not the pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing an `uint8_t *` as a `const uint8_t *&` parameter would allow the function to replace the `unint8_t *` with a `const uint8_t *`. Now there is a `const uint8_t *`in the place where the caller expects a modifiable `uint8_t *`. This is not save, since the caller might modify the pointed-to data after the function returned.

The problem is the same as in [this C++ FAQ lite section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html).